# Variables variables possible in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im working in a basic translation service for angularjs, I have an object in the view with the translations this way:

```
var translations = {"name":"Name", "address":"Address", "phone":"Telephone"};
```

So I want to replace if I found the {{phone}} in the view with the value of its translation: "Telephone".

Is there some way to call variables variables while iterate, like this:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="(k, v) in profile_fields">
    <b>{{translations. {{k}} }}</b> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use this:

```
<b>{{translations[k]}}</b>
```

Basically, access the `translations` object like you would in JavaScript, using the `k` variable.

Keep in mind that you never have to nest those brackets (`{{}}`) deeper than this.
Also, [Angular Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) is a pretty nice translations library. You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Im using Angular Translate in part of the project, the static part. But this app, needs to be connected to several sites and load different translations files from each site using web services. So the translation are dynamic and can change several times, is also possible that one site has one file translation for english, and other sites have different translations for English. I didn't find a way to get it working using Angular Translate, because the translations has to be setted in the start of the app, but the web services that I call to get the translations has to be called after that.

Comment: Have you had a look at [asynchronous loading](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading) yet?